# enhancement for gwt-ext

Tags: javascript, gwt, extjs, gwt-ext

Commonly, I create default GridPanel like new GridPanel(xxx, 480, 200, 1, 5) and I can control which column should be hidden through the first parameter in the constructor of gridpanel.

For example, I create a gridpanel like below and I want to hide the column called **description**.

```
public static xxx[] grdFundOutputs = { 
        new xxx("ID", "id", Integer.class, 50),
        new xxx("Name", "name", String.class, 100),
        new xxx("Description", "description", String.class, 150,true),//true represent hidden
        new xxx("Amount", "amount", Float.class, 70),
};
public static GridPanel createGrid(){
    return new GridPanel(grdFundOutputs, 480, 200, 1, 5);
}
```

**note**:I used xxx to indicate the classname, because I cannot expose it to the public due to the extension for the gwt-ext by my company.

My requirement is that I didn't hope user can manually make the hidden column  re-shown by clicking the checkbox like following action in image.
[image]

How can I implement this requirement, because of gwt-ext , I think it's hard for me to change the manner of ext-js.I hope to add a function to the class GridPanel so that developer can invoke it to let the  checkbox hidden.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can add this method to my own code and invoke it before gridpanel's construction

```
 private native void unableHiddenReShown()/*-{
        $wnd.Ext.override($wnd.Ext.grid.GridView, {
                       beforeColMenuShow : function(){
            var cm = this.cm,  colCount = cm.getColumnCount();
            this.colMenu.removeAll();
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++){
                if(cm.config[i].fixed !== true && cm.config[i].hideable !== false && !cm.isHidden(i) //!cm.isHidden(i) was added to solve this problem){
                    this.colMenu.add(new $wnd.Ext.menu.CheckItem({
                        id: "col-"+cm.getColumnId(i),
                        text: cm.getColumnHeader(i),
                        checked: !cm.isHidden(i),
                        hideOnClick:false,
                        disabled: cm.config[i].hideable === false
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
            });
        }-*/;
```